# php regex to delete from word to file end

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

In php I need a Regular Expression using `preg_replace()` function to delete from specific word to End Of File.

For example file could be similar to:

```
Hi, I'm Stefy,
this is my friend:
<div id="friend">Mr. Brown</div>.
```

and I would remove from **is my friend** to EOF, to obtaining:

```
Hi, I'm Stefy,
this
```

Someone can help me please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could  use DOTALL modifier here.

```
(?s)is\s+my\s+friend:.*$
```

Replacing the matched characters with an empty string will give you the desired output.

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/wU8uM7/20)

```
<?php
$string =<<<EOT
Hi, I'm Stefy,
this is my friend:
<div id="friend">Mr. Brown</div>.
EOT;
$pattern = "~(?s)is\s+my\s+friend:.*$~";
$replacement = "";
echo preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $string);
?>
```

**Output:**

```
Hi, I'm Stefy,
this
```